# Subscribe to others' questions

Tags: feature-request, notifications, bookmarks

I have been coming across many interesting questions on this site, for which I really like to know the answers; but, there is no way (at least I'm not aware of) to get notified when answers are posted to those questions.

Comment: You don't actually get notifications to favourites (unless you count that stuff in your profile; which I don't)

Comment: Obviously, you can "subscribe" to a question, so I guess this is really about notifications. How do you want to be notified? Marking a question as a favorite provides an Inbox notification, IIRC. Do you want to be notified via email?

Comment: anyone know where the [tag:support] version of this question is? what if we don't want to request a feature but find the best way to do it with the current state of the system (even if it is hacky like using IFTTT to subscribe to the RSS feed)?

Comment: A feature for following posts was now implemented, more details can be found [in the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info).

Answer (score 14):

You can subscribe to the rss feed of a particular question:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/34481

This way you will get notified by [include favorite rss reader].

Comment: It would be really good if you could be notified by email as in questions you left an answer though.

Comment: I agree. I don't have an RSS Reader and I'm not exactly authorized to install such products on my work PC.

Comment: @jp2code: Install something? That's so 2008... try http://reader.google.com ;-)

Comment: This is going to make me sound stupid, but I have no idea how to get a feed (like this) to load in Google Reader. I've tried, but I am obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: @jp2code: 1) Click on the big button labeled "Add subscription" on top 2) paste the url of your feed 3) Click Add 4) ... 5) Profit!

Comment: I agree with @obvio171 - I have so many subscriptions, I don't always get a chance to keep up with them all. Not that my inbox is much lighter, but at least it's more direct (and includes weight - thanks Gmail Priority Inbox!).

Comment: Why now allow a subscribe to thread priviledge when user has enough points?  The priviledge could add a special tab similar to the favorite questions tab.

Comment: The link is unavailable. `Page Not Found`

Comment: @ShijuKBabu Apparently, the url of this page changed from "meta.stackoverflow.com" to "meta.stackexchange.com". I updated the link. Thanks for noticing ;-)

Comment: The link says `Page Not Found`. How does it work now?

Comment: The updated link is dead too, now.

Answer (score 12):

As [Jeff has explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52093/162705), you are notified of any activity on questions that you have marked as a favorite.

For more information, see [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Comment: While this work, it feels like misusing the favorite functionality. Sometimes I want to follow the development of a question without considering it a favorite.

Comment: Its also worth noting that some folks don't use RSS feeds. I look at the model and say: do I want to send a continuous feed of possibly tainted data for processing? The answer is NO, so I don't use them. The Browser security model is such a joke at times.

Comment: As it appears, this is no longer true.

Answer (score 7):

Complementing **fretje**'s answer: when you are *reading* a question, the RSS link is at the end of the page (before the footer), right side, labeled "question feed".

[image]

Comment: same is true if you are on a specific tag page

Answer (score 6):

You could get the [StackStalker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paoeolblihedcagbofkkkecjilmpehmo) Chrome extension on the Chrome Web Store. Although I haven't used it, it appears to do what you want.

Comment: It works, this answer should have more upvotes!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than having to subscribe to an RSS feed for each question, a "Subscribe" button could aggregate all question subscriptions into a single RSS feed on each user's profile page.

This way, subscription to that user-specific RSS feed would be all that's required.  And we wouldn't keep overflowing feed quotas for services like [Feed My Inbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/).

Comment: You can click the "Star" right below a question's voting arrows to mark it as a favorite. You can then track updates to favorites via the appropriate section of your profile.