# Subscribe to a particular question by email (not RSS)

Tags: feature-request, support, notifications, subscription

Suppose I want to subscribe to all activity in response to a question I am interested in. I am  aware of the [existence of an RSS feed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/subscribe-to-others-questions), but I want email notifications. How do I do this?

Comment: But why. Whyyyyy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are services that will send the content of RSS feeds to your email inbox, for example, [Feed Mailer](http://www.feedmailer.net/). Of course that's not optimal, but it's a decent workaround.

Comment: [Feed My Inbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/) is another one.

Answer (score 12):

I use [IFTTT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifttt).

A recipe like https://ifttt.com/recipes/4447 will send new RSS entries to your e-mail based on the template variables you specify in the e-mail template.

Comment: Very helpful, thx :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't subscribe to a specific question made by someone else by email.

If it's your own question, you can get emails when new answers are posted using the link at the bottom of the "Ask Question" page or at the bottom of the page below all the answers for questions that have already been posted.

For your own questions you're also notified when someone comments on them, so you could have [your inbox notifications emailed to you](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/), but it's not per-post or limited to responses to your own questions.

Last but not least, there is no way to subscribe by email to *all* activities (edits, comments, etc.) even for your own posts.

Comment: Thanks - I see email notification option as described in the above link. Problem: At the bottom of this very page, I do not see "Would you like responses to your questions sent to you by email?" option.

Comment: I cannot see the part you mention in _If it's your own question, you can get emails when new answers are posted using the link at the bottom of the "Ask Question" page_. Is it still available?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [answer/comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113811/169587) (thx Yi Jiang's 独角兽), the email settings moved. There should be a link (it reads "email settings") in the bottom bar of the popup that appears when you press the Stack Exchange button (top-left of web page) that will take you to your email settings.  In said email settings dialogue, maximum frequency of notification is every 3 hours (as of today, anyway).

Comment: The email settings moved. There should be a button in the bottom bar of the popup that appears when you press the Stack Exchange button that will take you there