# Tool to get notified when there is a new question in a tag

Tags: discussion, tags, notifications, feed

I know you an [subscribe to an RSS feed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/) to get the questions for specific tags. I wonder if there are any tools beside email, like browser plugins to get noticed, as I'm not using any RSS reader.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subscribe to a particular question by email (not RSS)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113630/subscribe-to-a-particular-question-by-email-not-rss)

Comment: Update my question that I'm not looking for email subscription.

Comment: For popular tags like [java] this would be madness but for specalist tags like [jmonkeyengine] it would be nice if you could have new questions come through the notifications (clogging up email would be a bit much though)

Answer (score 3):

<s>Well, there's always email:</s> (removed re question update)

You could  just leave the page browsing those tag(s) open on a tab somewhere, and it will notify you of new questions in the title bar:

[image]

and on the page:

[image]

(which you can click to get the new questions)

You can monitor multiple tags this way, for example here's [java, .net and python on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+.net+or+python)

Answer (score 2):

IFTTT is always a great tool for this kind of thing.  Here's my recipe for getting an email on a new question in a tag:  https://ifttt.com/recipes/104384

Answer (score 1):

Did you noticed the " question with new activity".

Are you looking for this kind of feature, if yes, then it is already implemented.

[image: Notification]

Answer (score 0):

The subscribe function and the RSS feed on tags are separate features. One allows you to get email notifications of questions in a tag. The other you read with an RSS reader.

To use, simply hover over a tag to get the tag card and click subscribe.

[image: subscription link]

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this hack. I use the [RSS notification alert extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-alert/lemgijjifkaldmklohlmjaplmfobgich) for chrome and add the RSS feeds for the specific tags.