# How do you watch questions in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subscribe to others' questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/subscribe-to-others-questions)
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

I see many questions here that I would like to know the answer too - Is it possible to watch a question so you are notified when other users answer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

click on star button which resides next to any question, Later you can find those question in your favourite section. If you are eager enough to know answer you will keep checking from your favourites.

It's like keeping a memory address reference.

Comment: Thanks :-) Never thought to click on the star - and it seems to simple a feature to be missing.

Answer (score 7):

You can subscribe to the RSS feed of a question as described here: [Subscribe to others' questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/subscribe-to-others-questions)

So the feed for this question would be

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/113669