# Watching questions progress over time on Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subscribe to others' questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/subscribe-to-others-questions)
>   [How do you watch questions in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113669/how-do-you-watch-questions-in-stack-overflow)

Is there a way to ***watch*** a question on Stackoverflow. Would be easier to track if there are any updates, answers or comments to it. Right now, I can only tag them as favorites and come back to check their status in the future. Would be great to get notified instead.

Either the option exists or there is a reason why it was never implemented. If none of this reasons hold true, this could be a nice to have feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Stack Exchange Notifier you are notified from every comment in reply to you, or any answer added to your questions. As for watching a specific question (so also one that you did not ask personally), I usually add them to Google feeds so that I am notified of every change.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is obvious, the Site works best when your online browsing and reading/answering questions and not looking in email waiting to be notified.