# How to subscribe to a question?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, favorites-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subscribe to others' questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/subscribe-to-others-questions)

For example I like a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295600/how-to-bind-property-to-value-of-property-in-xaml) and I want to know the new answers or comments on the question.

Is there any way to subscribe to the question and StackExchange notify me ?

Comment: You can find some ways here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/subscribe-to-others-questions?rq=1